# gnu parallel vs multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tesseract, gnu-parallel

What is the difference between **GNU-parallel** and the python **multiprocessing** module? And also which one would be ideal for which circumstances, if they differ in usage.

I am trying to parallelize tesseract and found someone recommending **GNU parallel** [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1600#issuecomment-393917656) on the tesseract issues.

I want to understand, which one would be ideal for which use case, before going with one over the other.

Also, I'm not getting the desired results from **gnu-parallel**, I can see 4 processes running in `top`, but they take a lot more time than python multiprocessing.

**1)For gnu-parallel:**

Time taken is 8 min 40s as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAqrJ.jpg)

I am using the following command:

```
ls image*.jpg | time parallel tesseract {} stdout -l hin
```

**top output** is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKpj6.jpg)

**2) Normal Tesseract using multipage feature.**

```
$ time tesseract imagelist.txt stdout -l hin
```

Speed can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb4Fv.jpg)

**3) Multiprocessing based pytesseract**

gives a greater speed increase to about 4-5 seconds.

> My **pdf** can be found
>   [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hj6KzpnEaFQy-2uaajmVaME1KmzNqOhZ)

I am using `convert_from_path from pdf2image` or `convert from imagemagick` to convert `pdf` to `image` as either `png` or `jpeg`.

Comment: Given that GNU Parallel takes 8m40s and normal multipage tesseract takes 0m12s I think they are not doing the same. The difference in time is simply too big. If you ran the first run with GNU Parallel, maybe tesseract cached output somehow and the other runs then simply used the cache.

Comment: @OleTange : Hi Ole thanks for the reply! I don't think, so the problem is with the caching (although I don't understand how this could happen, and would love to know more), since my friend who hasn't got **gnu-parallel** installed gets the same speed. I am still thinking that I maybe using `gnu-parallel` wrongly, or some other reason. I can link to the pdf or images here, if you'd like to test them yourself, it'd also be a huge help.

Comment: Please do. That way the question will be an MCVE.

Comment: @OleTange : I've added the **pdf** link in the question at the bottom

Comment: Wow! I can actually reproduce your findings: tesseract becomes crazy slow. It goes faster if you run `--tty -j+0`, but the multipage feature is the fastest.

Comment: @OleTange : I don't understand why this should happen, python multiprocessing is even faster. But, I believe **GNU-parallel** , should give atleast the same amount of speed as **multiprocessing** does. Would love an explanation, as to why this occurs.

Comment: Me too. I have never seen a behaviour like this with any other tool. Hope some "tesseractors" can give us an explanation.

Comment: Sometimes some process try to get access to some limited resources. And if you run multiple processes witch try to get access to same resource then they spend most of time on waiting (spinning lock).

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota Yup, but what limited resource would that be for `tesseract`? Any why does it only show up when started from GNU Parallel?

Comment: Eg. you found that creating additional tty devices speedup work. So one of such resource can be `tty`.

Answer (score 0):

In python multiprocessing you have possibility of communication between processes. But then you have cost of synchroniazation. gnu pararell runs command multiple time with different parameters. Then You need aggregate results in other process.

Comment: When I'm trying to use `tesseract` with `gnu-parallel`, I can see 4 tesseract jobs being created and CPU going to near 100% for all the cores, but I don't get the speedup? I don't understand why. Say, I have 4 images created, I use : `ls image*.jpg | time parallel tesseract {} stdout -l hin`

Comment: There may be few reasons.  If `tesseract` is parallel inside adding new jobs do not increase speed. Second thing is access to hard drive. Hard drive has maximum seed of reading/saving data. And if one process exhaust this limit then adding next processes may slow operations. Also some specific decision of software developers can produce problem with multiple instances (some limited resource, like data file blocked by one process)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is analyzed here:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/3109

Solution:

```
export OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1
```

before running `tesseract` in parallel.